# Android Twitter is not returning sometimes to my Android app

Tags: android, twitter

I have made an Android app integrating Twitter. Where my callback URL is not returning to my Android app. Sometimes it shows web page not available. It has been removed or dwon. I have used `Twitter_Test_App Activity://callback` as call back URL. And gave it also in my manifest..

Answer (score 0):

Use below URL as a callback url.

```
public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "x-oauthflow-twitter://callback";
```

Comment: i tried this one also..but sometimes it works.and sometimes it show it has been removed or down.

Comment: @LaxmiKant the above solution is not working into 4.0 API or greater than 4.0 API.

Comment: @LaxmiKant if this answer is helping you, then please accept it.